# Is a renter allowed to withhold rent if the landlord does not fulfill his duties?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, real-estate, rental

If a landlord drags his feet on fixing things in his property, is the renter allowed to withhold rent until he does so? Alternatively, may the renter bring someone to fix it himself and pay from the rent?

Are there any sources which discuss these matters?

Comment: In most modern cases, Dina deMalchuta Dina would seem to apply here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, absent specification of a locality, I'd assume that the question is about what Choshen Mishpat says.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I agree, but it was still worth noting.

Comment: http://www.businesshalacha.com/articles/landlord-%E2%80%93-tenant-troubles-rabbi-max-sutton-case-studies